# Command to Call 'Turn Off Computer' Menu

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I remember there is (or was) a command involving `rundll32` that calls Windows XP's 'Turn Off Computer' menu – the one that can also be invoked by going to *Start Menu > Turn Off Computer*.

[image]

Does anyone happen to know/remember what the command is?

P.S.: I'm not talking about the 'shutdown' command.

Final edit: Well, the closest command to get this result with rundll32 is the following:

```
rundll32 msgina.dll,ShellShutdownDialog
```

But note that you'll get the 'classic' menu/dialog instead of the modern, 'themed' version.
You can get the latter using a VBScript one-liner posted by techie007 below.

Comment: Are you sure that was not in Windows 95/98/ME? I think it was replaced, and the functionality removed. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/rundll.php I tried the one for shutdown, and it errors out.

Comment: @KCotreau: No, I'm not sure, actually. I just have blurry keywords in my memory.

Comment: I looked VERY hard to find your answer, but I could not. I am not sure you can any more.

Comment: @KCotreau: Sorry for getting you worked up, then. I think I'm giving up on this as well. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: No problems. I was just letting you know by saying "VERY", that I did not give it a cursory look, so you would not likely find that, and maybe you might not want to kill yourself looking. As far as getting worked up, I have enjoyed answering questions, and it is questions like yours that have made me learn more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have rightfully pointed out, those commands don't work and/or shouldn't be used.

Here's an option, you can use scripting to call that shutdown dialog/menu (it just pops up the shutdown menu; it doesn't select any action).  Here's a couple basics to get you started:

VBS:

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShutdownWindows
```

Save as `Something.vbs` and run it with `cscript Something.vbs`.

PowerShell:

```
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).ShutdownWindows();
```

You can get PowerShell 2.0 for XP (etc.) from MS [here (KB968930)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968930).

These should work on all versions of XP and up (the VBS may work on Windows 2000 as well).  I tested them on Windows 7 (Ultimate) and they worked.

Comment: Good find. The VBScript one-liner does what I want. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4):

Before XP, there was a command, `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHExitWindowsEx 1`. It use to still work in XP.  It doesn't work in my XP VM though. . .

Starting with XP, Microsoft includes the shutdown command, which does **exactly** what you want, and more.  It works with remote computers, etc etc.

Edit:

There is the more popular Lock Computer command that a lot of people don't know about.

<strike>`rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation`</strike>

**edit:**

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043

Apparently, the above is a no no. So looks like we are stuck with PsShutdown.

Comment: The point of my comment above was that that very command does not work.

Comment: I didn't see your comment when I posted.  Abort, Retry, Fail.

Comment: No worries.  :).

Comment: [Do not call these functions through `rundll`.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Again, as in my comments, I believe that has been superseded primarily by the shutdown command, which you clearly know about.

If you would like alternatives, try these:

> `shutdown -i` *(to make it interactive, although not the screen you wanted)*
>
> `WMIC OS Where Primary=TRUE Call Shutdown` *(I tested this, works 100%)*
>
> `WMIC OS Where Primary=TRUE Call Reboot`

Not sure if WMIC is on XP Home though.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have focus on the desktop and you hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> that should invoke the 'Turn Off Computer' menu.